# Loading babel with the 'hungarian' (magyar) option breaks 'pygments' code highlighting

Tags: babel, incompatibility, highlighting, minted, hungarian

Given the following `TeX` file everything works as expected: the (Hungarian) text `Árvíztűrő Tükörfúrógép` typesetted as expected and the code snippet also formatted brilliantly.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{verbments}
\begin{document}
\section{Text}
Árvíztűrő Tükörfúrógép.

\section{Java}
\begin{pyglist}[language=java]
public static void main(String[] args) {
  int sum = 0;
  for (int i = 0; i < 0; i++)
    sum += i;
  System.out.format("Sum: %s.\n", sum);
}
\end{pyglist}
\end{document}
```

However if I specify that I want to use the Hungarian `babel` package with `\usepackage[magyar]{babel}`, I receive some cryptic errors (possibly related to the code generated by `Pygments`). (The log file containing the actual error message can be found [here](http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=4Z6pfFzy).)

I use `verbments` in this sample, but the same thing applies to `minted`.

Edit.: I forgot to mention, that loading *any* `babel` package (like English, German, etc.) does *not* results in errors.

Second edit.: I forgot to phrase a question, so here I go: *what could be the problem,* and *what could be the solution?* I'm utterly confused.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, I've found the solution.

The Hungarian `babel` package redefines some *active characters* (whatever those would be) which characters are used by the `Pygments` library to generate `LaTeX` code.

One has to use the `magyarOptions` (before loading the `babel` package) and set the `active=none` option (which means something like: *do not use or redefine active characters* - the ` [backtick] is used as an active character by the way). `shorthandcs=none` has to be set along the way, because the package complains otherwise...

```
\def\magyarOptions{defaults=prettiest,active=none,shorthandcs=none}
```

I've ruined a whole day with this, I hope someone makes good use of it!

Comment: You should mark your answer as "accepted" to show that this is the preferred way.

Comment: I've just registered to TeX Exchange, so I've to wait for a couple of hours before I can do that.

Comment: welcome here! I hope you enjoy tex.se as much as I do.

Comment: I have the exact same problem, and your solution does not work for me. I use a fairly old version of TeX Live (2009), can that be the problem?

Comment: @KovBal After answering my own question a year ago I abandoned `Pygments` and `minted` altogether, so I'm not sure. Anyway, I went with `listings` instead. It is much easier and faster to use than other solutions.

Comment: @KohányiRóbert sorry to hear that, I can't use `listings` for my current project.